# Selected value in combo box to open another worksheet in Excel VBA/User form

Tags: excel, vba

How to apply another method after selecting the value from combo box?
I have a list of names in worksheet"Home" and for each name in Range "C" they were a single worksheet linked containing the information of that name as mention in the image.

[Excel sheet picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiaZM.jpg)

I did a user form containing a combo box and some labels referring to the user name information , I need when I select the user name from the combo box the excel will go and open the page of that user name and retrieve the information from there.

[Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Ard.jpg)

Also, I am facing a problem with selecting the names from "Home" page. I used this code

```
cboUserList.List = wsHome.Range("c12", Range("c12").End(xlDown)).Value
```

but it is showing Method 'Range' of object'-Worksheet'failed.

This is my code for the command button "Import"

```
Private Sub cmdImport_Click()

cboUserList.List = wsHome.Range("c12", Range("c12").End(xlDown)).Value

lstActivationDate.List = ActiveSheet.Range("h2", Range("h2").End(xlDown)).Value

lstPaidDate.List = ActiveSheet.Range("c2", Range("c2").End(xlDown)).Value

lblUserID.Caption = [f2]

lblsubscType.Caption = ActiveSheet.Range("i2").End(xlDown).Value

lblamount.Caption = ActiveSheet.Range("j2").End(xlDown).Value

lblamountpaid.Caption = ActiveSheet.Range("d2").End(xlDown).Value


lbldate.Caption = Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy")

lbldebts.Caption = Range("f5:f6").Item(1).Value

lblNotes.Caption = [f13]


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea to get your code to work: Add wsHome to the second range too. `cboUserList.List = wsHome.Range("c12", wsHome.Range("c12").End(xlDown)).Value`

To populate the ComboBox try to use `cboUserList.AddItem(<String>)`. Loop through your range to get all elements into the ComboBox. Alternatively try to to use an array containing your names with `.List`.

To switch to the Workbook of the User you have to use this piece of code in your **userform** code:

```
Private Sub cboUserList_Change()
     Worksheets(Cstr(wsHome.Range("c12", wsHome.Range("c12").End(xlDown)).Find(cboUserList.Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, 1).Value)).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Freakfeuer for the cboUserList.List = wsHome.Range("c12", wsHome.Range("c12").End(xlDown)).Value code now it works fine but regarding the selected value in combo box how can I make this value to open the worksheet was linked to ?

Comment: I edited my anwer. I guess what you are looking for was `Worksheets(X).Activate`.

Comment: I used your edit code <-- Worksheets(wsHome.Range("c12", wsHome.Range("c12").End(xlDown)).Find(cboUserList.Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, 1).Value).Activate -->' but I changed the offset row from 0 to 1 .offset(1,1) and it works fine but I faced another issue when I chose the last user name which is located in C311 it is showing run time error "9" Subscript of range.

Comment: I guess excel is interpreting the value as an integer and therefore uses the worksheet number and not the name (so your second sheet is number _2_ while the name is _"1"_). I am very sure you don't need the row offset at all (according to your picture). I added `Cstr()` into my answer. That should convert the integer into a string and therefore use the name. @AhmedEjam

Comment: I applied your code and it is working fine many thanks but one thing more how can I create an automatic receipt number starting from "Alnoor-1" and after printing this userform will be increased to next number "Alnoor-2" and etc

Comment: Great, nice to know that. If your initial question is answered please let the other users also know it by accepting the answer as correct. I suggest to add a new question for your automatic receipt number since I'm not very experienced in printing topics. @AhmedEjam

Comment: Again Thanks brother.